# Facebook: Automated posting on others walls

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, jsoup

It appears that Facebook has removed the ability to post on friends walls in it's api. I'm wondering if this is still at all possible through third party applications at all? For example I can parse a list of friends pages/urls with associated dates using Jsoup(Java html **scraper** ), but I'm unfamiliar with the Facebook webpage interactions. Is anyone familiar with how to do this?

Comment: I'm anticipating downvotes on this question, however if you downvote I would appreciate advice on resources I should check or how to make the question more appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and there are no third party applications for this either. Btw, scraping is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You get access to friends by using the `/me/friends` endpoint, and you only get friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons. In other words: Users who did not authorize your App are none of your business. More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: Alright that explains why this was so hard to find info on. Thanks.